# Seeds of a great war

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> A golden one's responsible for sparking a great war.
>   An earthly one has earthly tones – no green, no red, no core.
>   A big one's home to sights that numerous travellers adore.
>   To purchase eye products one needs to find a certain store.

The answer is one word.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the seeds of this story at the core concern

> **apple**

A golden one's responsible for sparking a great war.

> The golden apple which Zeus sent to Paris of Troy caused the Trojan war.

An earthly one has earthly tones – no green, no red, no core.

> A grown potato (pomme de terre) is commonly brownish with seeds on the skin.

A big one's home to sights that numerous travellers adore.

> New York City - the Big Apple.

To purchase eye products one needs to find a certain store.

> iMacs, iPads and iPhones from the Apple store.

Answer (score 4):

Is it a

> chair?

A golden one's responsible for sparking a great war.

> The war of the golden stool was a series of conflicts between the British Imperial government of the Gold Coast (later Ghana) and the Ashanti Empire

An earthly one has earthly tones – no green, no red, no core.

> furniture can be in earth tones

A big one's home to sights that numerous travellers adore.

> The Lincoln Memorial features a very large chair and is in Washington DC, home to numerous tourist attractions.

To purchase eye products one needs to find a certain store.

> I-kea sells chairs

Comment: I'm not sure how you make the third line ("A big one's...") relevant to the answer. Sure, rot13(vg srngherf n ovt punve), but I can't see any relationship with the answer further than that.